# Fancybox 2 with dragable window, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox vesion 2.1.5, and I want the popup window will be dragable. is there any option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native support for dragability in fancybox2, you might want to look into: [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and combine the two